Pass multiple S3 files to AWS Textract API in Lambda function
I have an image of a PDF containing several text fields that I want to pass to AWS Textract for text extraction. I have thus created cropped images of these specific text boxes. In order to keep all of these boxes straight (and able to determine which image came from which field), I am operating primarily within a dictionary and created a function to call on the Textract API and enter the resulting response as an entry in the dictionary. An example of the dictionary and the code is below.
However, this method is incredibly slow as I am submitting hundreds of images to populate the fields of the dictionary. I cannot figure out how to implement some sort of parallel processing or how I can submit multiple images in one call (and keep them all straight). How can I speed up this task and decrease my processing time? With current code it takes approximately 7 minutes to extract all the text from all the images, and I need to be done in no more than 45 seconds.
I did attempt to write the API call as response = textract_client.detect_document_text(Document={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket_name,'Name': ["sa1.png", "sa2.png", "sb1.png"]}}) but that threw an error because you cannot put a list of files into the file name.
Dictionary example
aws_output = {
    "Section A": {"1": extract_text(imgs['Section A']['1'], "sa1"), 
                  "2": extract_text(imgs['Section A']['2'], "sa2")}, 
    "Section B": {"1": extract_text(imgs['Section B']['1'], "sb1")}
    }

Function
def extract_text(img, loc):
        img_obj = Image.fromarray(img).convert('RGB')
        out_img_obj = io.BytesIO()
        img_obj.save(out_img_obj, format="png")
        out_img_obj.seek(0)
        file_name = key_id + "_" + loc + ".png"
        s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=file_name, Body=out_img_obj, ContentType="image/png")
        response = textract_client.detect_document_text(
            Document={
                'S3Object': {
                    'Bucket': bucket_name,
                    'Name': file_name
                }
            }
        )
        status_code = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']
        try: 
            status_code == 200
            text_len = {}
            for y in range(len(response['Blocks'])):
                if 'Text' in response['Blocks'][y]:
                    text_len[y] = len(response['Blocks'][y]['Text'])
                else:
                    pass
            if bool(text_len):
                extracted_text = response['Blocks'][max(text_len, key=text_len.get)]['Text']
                if extracted_text == '-':
                    extracted_text = ''
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                extracted_text = ''
            s3.Object(bucket_name,file_name).delete()
            return extracted_text
        except:
            return f"HTTP Status code is not 200 when running extract_text on {loc}, code is {status_code}"


Textract can process requests in parallel. The hard part is figuring out how to change your program to make those parallel requests. Instead of calling detect_document_text() that waits until the results are complete, you could call start_document_text_detection(), which will start an asynchronous process without making your Python program wait. Do this for every image. Then, you can then retrieve the results with get_document_text_detection() for each previously-submitted request.
